# Match-up between Ten Forward windows (interior) and Enterprise D exterior

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise, production

Is this a production goof or am I just not seeing the connection?

Am I wrong or do the windows of Ten Forward not fit anywhere on the complete saucer section exterior of the Enterprise D? Shots appearing in season 2 episode 1 "The Child" which include a view looking in to Ten Forward seem to create more of a disconnect. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have any reference images to help us see the 'disconnect' you mention?

Comment: Ex Astris mentions that the original model only had two sets of windows whereas the final production had two sets of three windows. You can see in the picture below.

Comment: This sounds familiar. I remember reading that this was a real problem, i.e. you're not imagining it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes, you can see it in the big version of my pic below; http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/galaxy/galaxy-windows.jpg

Comment: Good catch - I never noticed that before.

Comment: I always thought Ten Forward was at the upper edge of the saucer, and never realized there was an inset section between the upper and lower sections - until now. Bearing in mind Richard's freehand illustration, it all makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ten forward was originally intended to be on the underside of the leading edge. The location can be seen clearly on the original deck plan by Senior Designer, Michael Okuda

[image]

Per [Ex Astris](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/galaxy.htm), the observation windows were ultimately moved up to top side of the leading edge, presumably so the set could be recycled into bedrooms or observation lounges as the need arose (e..g all of which have windows that slope inwards).

[image]

The "disconnect" you're describing may come from the fact that earlier episodes used a slightly different (4ft) model from later episodes. The earlier model matched the floor plan exactly, with three forward windows whereas the later model only had two sets of windows.

Comment: "Ten forward was originally intended to be on the underside of the leading edge. (...) the observation windows were ultimately moved up to top side of the leading edge" - Ten Forward is *still* supposed to be on the underside. The Ex Astris Scientia article merely describes that what was originally intended to be one deck (with observation windows at the top *and* at the bottom) was split up into two decks (the lower of which, deck 10, contains the lower observation windows, behind some of which Ten Forward is located).

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, the first model built for the effect shots of Enterprise D did not have the Ten Forward windows in the right place.

During the third season a second smaller, but more detailed model was built that did have windows that matched up with the Ten Forward set.

The model was first used in "The Defector".

***Source:***

The *Star Trek the Next Generation* Companion.